# How can I space imgs inside a div without modifing the padding?

Tags: html, css

I have a Div containing 4 images of the same size, placed in a row. I want them to occupy all the space avaible in the div by staying in the same row, with the first image in the far left and the fourth image in the far right, they also have to be equally spaced. I can accomplish this by modifying the padding of each image so I'm asking if there is a method to do it automatically.

```
<div>
  <img src="imgsrc\html5.svg" id="htmLogo" class="iconPgr">
  <img src="imgsrc\java.svg" id="javaLogo" class="iconPgr">
  <img src="imgsrc\python.svg" id="pythonLogo" class="iconPgr">
  <img src="imgsrc\C++ icon.png" id="cLogo" class="iconPgr">
</div>
```

```
#htmLogo {
padding-left: 35px
padding-right: 0px

/* I repeat the same for every ID with different padding values so the imgs result equally spaced with htmLogo in the far right and cLogo in the far left */
```

Comment: Please add a code example what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox.  Read more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#my-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
</div>
```

Comment: It works, It was a grid container and that was the problem, so I made another div inside with flex properties.

Answer (score 0):

if bootstrap is available and you can change the html then you can wrap each image in a div and use bootstrap's grid system ([here is a demo](https://codepen.io/carnnia/pen/ZNprZa)).

```css
#container{
  width: 100%; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.row{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 


<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/23/23735.svg" width=50 height=50 /></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/14675-telegram-logo1.png" width=50 height=50/></div>    
    <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgWDI1YcQTcTa2IoQn_yuEXtWwuLy7KbkFZ5H-2F3554d_j29nAQ" width=50 height=50/></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/130/130484.png" width=50 height=50/></div>

  </div><!-- row END -->
</div>  <!-- container END -->
```